# Building a Java project which does not have javadoc.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, javadoc

I need to use some java library in MATLAB. I did use it in MATLAB (Unix version), but now I have to do it on MATLAB (Win64), as well. As far as I know, this is a project developed in unix. I did simply compile it using

```
ant
```

command in Ubuntu.

Since I'm a beginner to java compiling, I thought of installing ant on Windows and running

```
c:\java\ant\bin\ant
```

command in the path. However when I do this, it says that:

```
build.xml:22: Javadoc failed: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "javadoc.exe": CreateProcess error=2
```

Here is the build.xml file:

```
<project default="all">

    <target name="all" depends="doc,jar" />

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="build/examples" />
        <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="on" srcdir="src/main/java"
            destdir="build/classes" target="1.5" />
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/main/example/"
            classpath="build/classes" destdir="build/examples" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="dist/java_websocket.jar">
            <fileset dir="build/classes" includes="**/*.class" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="doc">
        <delete dir="doc" />
        <javadoc sourcepath="src/main/java" destdir="doc" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

</project>
```

When I try to search about this issue, I've come up with so many answers that are about Java Eclipse compilations, which I'm a total stranger to.

If you use maven to compile these projects, thats fine. I just need some guidance.

Here is the github link of the java project that I'm trying to compile (on Win64), if you would like to see any further information: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

And here is the build instructions (I'm guessing for Unix): https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/README.markdown

Note that I sadly use Windows 8 (x64) and I currently have jdk1.7.0_21 installed on the path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21" which is also the system variable JAVA_HOME. ANT_HOME variable is "c:\java\ant"

Please take a moment from your precious time and help me to find a solution, if you have any knowledge about this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it compiles on ubuntu with just ant, there is no need for either maven or eclipse. The problem is likely that the PATH variable does not include the jdk. Look into c:\Programs\Java and find the javadoc.exe. Its directory must go into PATH. To set the dir in PATH, go to (roughly, have no windows around) computer / properties / advanced / environment variables / system and find the PATH variable. Append the directory you found by using semicolon as the separator.

Comment: I will check on that now

Comment: It's in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin. But how do I edit build.xml to make it compilable with this javadoc, exactly?

Comment: I did what you said, but I'm afraid I'm getting the same error with win ant.

Comment: Type javadoc on the command line. Does it start? If not, start a new powershell or cmd.exe, because only then the fresh PATH will be picked up.